# Autonomous Navigation of ROS through rviz

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am new to ROS. So, I have some simple doubts.

**1. If multiple goals is set through rviz window, then which goal Robot will take to move?**

2.**If 2D Pose Estimate button doesn't work properly, then will the 2D Nav Goal somehow manage to move towards the goal?**

**3. After starting the autonomous navigation, can the teleop operation be started again? Is there any procedure?**

**4. What should global_frame and robot_base_frame for local_costmap_params.yaml and global_costmap_params.yaml?**

Thanks for your time.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/120301/autonomous-navigation-of-ros-through-rviz/) by [Mercy](https://answers.ros.org/users/8381/mercy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2014-01-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am not an expert, but this is what I think from my experience so far:

**1)** In rviz I think you can only set one goal at a time. If your robot is navigating and you use the 2D Navigation button again, your robot will forget what it was doing and navigate to the new goal.

**2)** I have never tried this, but I imagine if the initial pose is far off it would be difficult for the robot to localize itself.

**3)** By autonomous navigation, do you mean this tutorial?
http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_navigation/Tutorials/Autonomously%20navigate%20in%20a%20known%20map

The tutorial includes this paragraph:

> > Teleoperation
>
> The teleoperation can be run
> simultaneously with the navigation
> stack. It will override the autonomous
> behavior if commands are being sent.
> It is often a good idea to teleoperate
> the robot after seeding the
> localization to make sure it converges
> to a good estimate of the position.

So I believe you should be able to run both simultaneously. If you're doing the autonomous tutorial you should already have your robot booted up, so I would think all you need to do is open a new terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and type in `roslaunch turtlebot_teleop keyboard_teleop.launch`
(I don't know what robot you're using. I am using a Turtlebot, so that is the teleop command for it)

**4)**
For local_costmap_params,

```
global_frame: /odom   
robot_base_frame: /base_footprint
```

For global_costmap_params,

```
   global_frame: /map
   robot_base_frame: /base_footprint
```

I hope this helps!

---

Originally posted by [BlitherPants](https://answers.ros.org/users/4967/blitherpants/) with karma: 504 on 2014-01-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mercy](https://answers.ros.org/users/8381/mercy/) on 2014-01-21**:
Thanks @BlitherPants.
For 2 do you have any concrete reason?

By autonomous navigation, I am referring to the scenario where move_base, amcl and rviz are used to move a robot to a particular goal.

**Comment by [BlitherPants](https://answers.ros.org/users/4967/blitherpants/) on 2014-01-21**:
For 2 I don't have a strong answer for you since I usually do autonomous navigation of an unknown map (gmapping instead of AMCL). I ran AMCLwhen I was going through the whole tutorial but never tried to put a wrong initial pose. I can try it later but I don't have the robot with me now, sorry...